# Customizing the jQuery-UI accordion

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div named `content` in my web page `index.html`, in which I load the contents from various other html pages using the following javascript. This happens whenever the user clicks on a link which has the class `myajaxreq`.

---

```
$('.myajaxreq').click(function() {
    var myhref=$(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').hide().load(myhref).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

---

I need to load a an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) on this div `content` on clicking one of the links, from the page `acc.html`. However, I am having a few problems with it:

---

(a) The accordion takes up all of the available width in the div `content`. I want it to occupy only some 60% of the div. I tried doing this in the `acc.html` page, ie from which I am loading the accordion

```
`<style type="text/css">
    #myaccordion {
    width: 60%;}
</style>`
```

---

(b) I do not want any border across the accordion main tabs. I know this seems easy, but I couldn't find the corresponding css for it.

Comment: (a) Why have the CSS directive in the page from which you load the accordion? It belongs in the page into which the accordion is loaded. (b) An unwanted border most probably arises from a CSS directives with a selector that is not specific enough, hence it affects element(s) other than the one(s) for which it is intended.

Answer (score 0):

use a browser console to inspect the elements css. You can even disable various properties by simply clicking on that property right in the console. You can also edit the property values in the console to test them.  This will help you isolate the rules you need to over ride